Rebuilding Jenkins job using curl command
I am trying to rebuild one Jenkins Job from one script using curl command:
curl -u user:pass "jenkins_job/2026/rebuild?autorebuild=true" -w "%{http_code}" -L -s -o /dev/null

It is working fine and taking the same parameters as in original job but while rebuilding i want to update the value of one of the parameters, i tried to use below command but it didn't work :
curl -u user:pass "jenkins_job/2026/rebuild?autorebuild=true&parameter_name='value'" -w "%{http_code}" -L -s -o /dev/null

How can i update the value only for one parameter and other parameter values should be same as in original job
